# Find souce code for eval() function Python

Tags: python, built-in

I am trying to modify the source code for the eval() function, in my own file, so I need the source code.

I have tried writing eval with an error, but that just says error in . I tried using the inspect function, but that said "TypeError:  is a built-in class
".

This is what I did for inspect:

```py
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(eval))
```

Can you tell me how to find it, or even just give me a link to github file?

Comment: Why do you want to modify `eval`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though some python functions are written in python, most core functions are actually implemented in C.

[Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3191391515824fa7f3c573d807f1034c6a28fab3/Python/clinic/bltinmodule.c.h#L326) is the source code for the `eval()` function.

Comment: Too bad I can't use it, since it is written in C

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762621/can-we-use-c-code-in-python