# How to convert python code into a simple c haeder?

Tags: python, c, cpython

I'm Working on a program that takes in text from the user and then implements functionalities in the backend, kind of like an interpreter, I have the parser working amazingly in python but some of the backend capabilities I feel would do great on c. I have looked into CPython but I don't seem to understand how to do it if it's even possible at all. I'm just a beginner, if someone could guide that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CPython` is just an implementation of Python in the C programming language. If you want to incorporate C code, you can write extension modules documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html).

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762621/can-we-use-c-code-in-python) StackOverflow post as well.

Alternatively, write a C program, compile it, and then call it via the subprocess module documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).